# Reading the Color Image from Kinect sensor into cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, types, kinect

I have a simple problem:

I hate having a RGB picture stored in an array and want to get it into an cv:Mat.

I have already done it with the Depth Image from the Kinect sensor like this:

```
VideoFrameRef lDepthFrame;
lStatus = gDepthVideoStream.readFrame(&lDepthFrame);

cv::Mat lDepthMat(lDepthFrame.getHeight(), lDepthFrame.getWidth(), CV_16U, (uint16_t*)lDepthFrame.getData());
```

my problem now is that I can't find out which type to use for the color Image (above I used CV_16U). The Color Image is in RGB888/RGB24. So it is 3 bytes big, one for each color.

so what I have for the Color Image is something like this:

```
VideoFrameRef lColorFrame;
lStatus = gRgbVideoStream.readFrame(&lColorFrame);
cv::Mat lRgbMat(lColorFrame.getHeight(), lColorFrame.getWidth(), <????>, (<????>*)lColorFrame.getData());
```

What do I need to replace the  in the above code to make this function work.

Thank you so much for reading and hopefully answering. I am really sorry for my English if there are to many misspellings in here. I am anything but a native speaker

Comment: CV_8UC3 for rgb image (3 8-bit channels)

Comment: Thanks that worked well. For the typecast before the lColorFrame i used (uint16_t*) just as above.  so if anyone is intrested the result looks like this:   `cv::Mat lRgbMat(lColorFrame.getHeight(), lColorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint16_t*)lColorFrame.getData());`

Comment: "for the typecast" - internally, it's a uchar* (but it does not matterat all, how you cast it there, a void* would do the very same thing)

Answer (score 0):

`RGB888` would be `CV_8UC3` in opencv-speak, 8bit unsigend values, with 3 channels.

There might be an issue if the RGB is actually BGR - but you can swap channels around later.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as this:

```
IColorFrame* pColorFrame = nullptr;
cv::Mat image;
if (SUCCEEDED(m_pColorFrameReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pColorFrame)) {

    // First you probably would like to get the image dimensions coming from your kinect device
    IFrameDescription* pFrameDescription = nullptr;
    int nWidth = 0;
    int nHeight = 0;

    pColorFrame->get_FrameDescription(&pFrameDescription);
    pFrameDescription->get_Width(&nWidth);
    pFrameDescription->get_Height(&nHeight);

    // now you just need to allocate your opencv matrix and copy the data from the IColorFrame object
    imageData.create(nHeight, nWidth , CV_8UC4);
    BYTE* imgDataPtr = (BYTE*)imageData.data;
    pColorFrame->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(nWidth * nHeight * 4, imgDataPtr, ColorImageFormat_Bgra);

    // release your pointer
    pFrameDescription->Release();
    pFrameDescription = nullptr;
}

pColorFrame->Release();
pColorFrame = nullptr;
```

Then later you can simply make use the opencv methods to display the image;

```
cv::imshow("Kinect Image", image);
```